# json_encode after array_unique returning associative array

Tags: php, json

```
$a = array("pear","apple","apple","ball","cat");
$u = array_unique($a);
echo json_encode($u);
```

The output appears as: {"0":"pear","1":"apple","3":"ball","4":"cat"}

I need a non-associative array as output as: ["apple","ball","cat","pear"].

Comment: Please tell why you need the non-associative array over the standard json-encoded one. The "problem" you're facing may be a non-issue really.

Comment: Then loop through your array and build a json string manually

Comment: @Ahmad: Building anything manually is usually a horrible idea, because people cannot be bothered to do it correctly. That's why we recommend `json_encode`, `http_build_query`, `htmlspecialchars` etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reindex the array with `array_values` before encoding it:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($u));
```

Comment: But that will be again the same array as before rite ? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @PrasanthBendra: [No, it won't](http://ideone.com/yil7FK). But the result you get without is dependent on which duplicate elements `array_unique` chooses to remove, which is AFAIK not deterministic from a PHP userland perspective. If it removes the second "apple" you don't need to reindex, but if it removes the first you do. You can't control this, so reindexing is necessary to be safe.

Comment: Reindexing seems to be the only solution. It would have been easier if array_unique() allowed to make a choice whether or not to preserve original index value.

Comment: @smaske: What would be the point? It's extremely easy to reindex if you need to.

Comment: You should check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25296770/2393077 for explanation why it's happening

Comment: getting slashes like this `[\\"flRHM7Ga9\\",\\"Hers4432ds\\"]`  after encode