# Array after array_unique function is returned as an object in JSON response

Tags: php, slim

im trying to merge two arrays with omitting duplicated values and return it as a JSON with Slim framework. I do following code, but in result I get `unique` property of a JSON as object - not as an array. I don't know why does it happen, and I'd like to avoid it. How can I do it?

My code:

```
$galleries = array_map(function($element){return $element->path;}, $galleries);
$folders = array_filter(glob('../galleries/*'), 'is_dir');

function transformElems($elem){
    return substr($elem,3);
}           
$folders = array_map("transformElems", $folders);

$merged = array_merge($galleries,$folders);
$unique = array_unique($merged); 

$response = array(
  'folders' => $dirs, 
  'galleries' => $galleries, 
  'merged' => $merged, 
  'unique' => $unique);
echo json_encode($response);
```

An as a JSON response I get:

```
{
folders: [] //array
galleries: [] //array
merged: [] //array
unique: {} //object but should be an array
}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cfHy8Od.png]

It seems that `array_unique` returns something strange, but what's the reason?

Comment: You'd get a JS object (`{}`) anytime your arrays have non-numeric keys, or even non-sequential numeric keys. Do a `var_dump($unique)` in PHP to see what's going on in there. The JS array shorthand that json uses doesn't allow numeric array keys to be specified. they have to be 0,1,2,....,n sequentially with no gaps, otherwise it forces an object.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`array_unique` removes values from the array that are duplicates, but the array keys are preserved.

So an array like this:

```
array(1,2,2,3)
```

will get filtered to be this

```
array(1,2,3)
```

but the value "3" will keep his key of "3", so the resulting array really is

```
array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 3 => 3)
```

And `json_encode` is not able to encode these values into a JSON array because the keys are not starting from zero without holes. The only generic way to be able to restore that array is to use a JSON object for it.

If you want to always emit a JSON array, you have to renumber the array keys. One way would be to merge the array with an empty one:

```
$nonunique = array(1,2,2,3);
$unique = array_unique($nonunique);
$renumbered = array_merge($unique, array());

json_encode($renumbered);
```

Another way to accomplish that would be letting array_values create a new consecutively-indexed array for you:

```
$nonunique = array(1,2,2,3);
$renumbered = array_values(array_unique($nonunique));

json_encode($renumbered);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've also found that I can use `array_values($unique)` instead of merge with an empty array. It looks a bit more clear for me ;)

Comment: This happened to me while using MongoDB, which internally uses JSON. I passed the array returned by array_unique to MongoDB, who then complained that it needs an array, coz the array got converted to object because of JSON.

Comment: this happened to me while using WordPress API... was very frustrating because I could var_dump it all out to the screen and see that it was a flat 1d array before getting "jsonified" by WP. Even though I could see that it was supposed to work, it was returning an object with numerical indices/keys that has been cast to strings.